# gl*Pointer-function for texture-bindings

Tags: opengl

While I looked at the definitions in gl.h ang glext.h I found `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_ARRAY`, I think it has to do with VBOs like `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` does, to enable the buffer set up with `glTexCoordArray`.

**Is there a vbo-function to bind texture-objects in an VBO** like you bind the coordinates of the texture with `glTexCoordArray`? And how to bind it to a triangle/quad and not a single vertex?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a vbo-function to bind texture-objects in an VBO

No.

The most you could do is employ [bindless textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture) and pass those as 64-bit integer values (which presumably you'll pass to the fragment shader). But that still only provides the value per-vertex, not per-primitive. So you'll still have to deal with [provoking vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Provoking_Vertex) issues.